# Unable to disable SSL3.0 in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7.5, openssl

I have tried to disable SSL3.0 on my Windows web server that is running Windows Server 2008R2 with IIS 7.5. I have entered the following registry keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\DES 56/56]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\NULL]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 40/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 56/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 64/128]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
```

After rebooting the server I have checked my site's SSL protocols using `nmap` and `openssl`.

**NMAP Command:**

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers mysite.com
```

**NMAP Output:**

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|_  least strength: strong
```

**OpenSSL Command:**

```
openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443 -ssl3
```

**OpenSSL Output:**

```
SSL handshake has read 2540 bytes and written 486 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : RC4-SHA
    Session-ID: (omitted...)
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: (omitted...)
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1415005218
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Could anyone please help me disable SSL3 on the server ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) to do this, seems to work just fine. Note that a full reboot is required after disabling/enabling encryption methods.

Comment: I will try this now and schedule a reboot for out of hours. If it works I will mark this as the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Can you please tell me what I need to disable using IIS Crypto? The SSL 3.0 is unchecked when I ran the tool. I presume I need to disable some of the SSL Ciphers? Can you tell me which ones please?

Comment: @Seany84 If SSL 3.0 already is unchecked then your registry changes worked - you probably didn't reboot? You could also do what I did and just select FIPS compliance to make sure that the cipher suites are correct etc..

Comment: I just checked the result of the scheduled task and it appears as though the reboot did not happen. I've fixed the scheduled task and will know tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that the registry setting disabled ssl3 only after the reboot. Thanks